# Using Repeater control in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am using a repeater control to view database table data, I want to add a link button next to each row to delete a specific row, how can I do that using vb.net??

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Did you google it? It's all over the place, for example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kannagoud/edit-update-delete-record-in-repeater-control/

Comment: I have only get data form the table, and viewed data in a repeater control, but I don't have any idea how to do that, I tried google, I found a lot of solutions, but nothing work with me

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-button-actions-with-the-datalist-and-repeater/custom-buttons-in-the-datalist-and-repeater-vb) it will show you how to populate a repeater from a datasource, along with how to add command buttons and to respond to their events

Comment: Please give me a simple example that I can understand the main concept about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to do much, do you want to display it(link button for all the rows? if yes then try the following code)

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr valign="top" class="list_heading">
                            <td width="25%">
                                Column
                            </td>
                            <td width="25%">
                                Operation
                            </td>
                            <td width="19%" style="display: none;">
                                And/Or
                            </td>
                            <td width="25%">
                                Value
                            </td>
                            <td width="06%">
                                Remove
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tbody>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rpSearchItems" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="display: none;">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%# Eval("ColumnName") %>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%# Eval("Operation") %>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="display: none;">
                                            <%# Eval("AndOr") %>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%# Eval("Value") %>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnRemoveSearchItem" ImageUrl="~/Controls/ImagesForSearch/Remove.png"
                                                CommandArgument=' <%# Eval("Id") %>' CssClass="RemoveUitem" ToolTip="Remove Item"
                                                runat="server" OnClick="ibtnRemoveSearchItem_Click" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </tbody>
                        <tr valign="top" class="list_bottom">
                            <td colspan="6">
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

And in code behind code you can go like this:

```
Protected Sub ibtnRemoveSearchItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
 ImageButton ibtnRemoveSearchItem = (ImageButton)sender;
    Int32 Id = Convert.ToInt32(ibtnRemoveSearchItem.CommandArgument);
//Using the above two lines you can get the Coomand Argument, pass it to you delete stored proc thats all
// do your stuff here
End Sub
```

hope this will help you

**UPDATE :**   If you want to add it conditionally then you can do it from "**OnItemDataBound**" event of repeater

for much info [review this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/438259/Insert-Update-Search-and-Delete-CRUD-operation-usi)

[This one also can help you](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kannagoud/edit-update-delete-record-in-repeater-control/)

Comment: can you please help me with delete a record?? I tried to write text in a lable, but no result accoured

Comment: @Alaa do you mean to say i need to write all the code for delete functionality for you?????

Comment: no, I mean if i want to delete a spicif row, what i write in this funtion?

Protected Sub ibtnRemoveSearchItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
??